# dividing a subplot using gridspecs to have 6 equal size buttons

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, subplot

I am new to data visualization world and has been assigned to create a 
    GUI(graphical user interface) to visualize data and have some fancy controls 
    in it. 
    The problem is that I am using subplots using gridspecs and I need to have 
    equal size buttons in "ax5 subplot" as shown in the figure. 
    I can't seem to find a solution to access that "ax5" and then divide this 
    area into 6 equal buttons.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


def make_ticklabels_invisible(fig):
    for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "ax%d" % (i+1), va="center", ha="center")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)


# demo 3 : gridspec with subplotpars set.

fig = plt.figure(facecolor = '#0F0F0F')

fig.suptitle("GridSpec w/ different subplotpars", color= '#e21f1f')

gs1 = GridSpec(3, 3)
gs1.update(left=0.01, right=0.49, wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[:-1, :-1])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[:-1, -1:])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[-1, :])


gs2 = GridSpec(3, 3)
gs2.update(left=0.50, right=0.98, hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05)
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[:-2, :])

# need to have six buttons in 5th subplot
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs2[-2:-1, :])
ax6 = plt.subplot(gs2[-1, :])

make_ticklabels_invisible(fig)
pos5 = ax5.get_position()
print(pos5)
plt.show()
```

[image: SamplePlot]

Comment: You can make a finer GridSpec, like 100 by 100, then just place the buttons inside the region you need.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks. any tutorial or example I can understand from?

Comment: Looks like you want to use a `gs2 = GridSpec(6, 3)` such that you can divide the area of what is now ax5 into a 2x3 grid.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Exactly, I want to bring multiple buttons in ax5. Any suggestions, how can you divide this area and plot some buttons there?

Comment: As said, use `gs2 = GridSpec(6, 3)` and instead of `ax5 = plt.subplot(gs2[-2:-1, :])`,   create some axes in that area, like e.g. `axbutton1 =  plt.subplot(gs2[2,0])`etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It worked. Much thanks..